# Initializing std::memset

Tags: c++, c++17, memset

I'm using `std::memset` to solve a [LeetCode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/cherry-pickup-ii/) copied here. Currently, `map_cherries` has been initialized as:

```
map_cherries[70][70][70] = {}
...
std::memset(map_cherries, -1, sizeof(map_cherries));
```

Is there a way to set up dimensions and values of `map_cherries` at the same time, or maybe any better/alternative way to do that? Thank you!

#### Problem

> Given a `rows x cols` matrix grid representing a field of cherries.
> Each cell in grid represents the number of cherries that you can
> collect.
>
> You have two robots that can collect cherries for you, Robot #1 is
> located at the top-left corner `(0,0)`, and Robot #2 is located at the
> top-right corner `(0, cols-1)` of the grid.
>
> Return the maximum number of cherries collection using both robots by
> following the rules below:
>
> - From a cell `(i,j)`, robots can move to cell `(i+1, j-1)` , `(i+1, j)` or `(i+1, j+1)`.
> - When any robot is passing through a cell, It picks it up all cherries, and the cell becomes an empty cell (0).
> - When both robots stay on the same cell, only one of them takes the cherries.
> - Both robots cannot move outside of the grid at any moment.
> - Both robots should reach the bottom row in the grid.
>
> Example 1:
>
> [image]
>
> Input: `grid = [[3,1,1],[2,5,1],[1,5,5],[2,1,1]]`
> Output: 24
>
> Explanation: Path of robot #1 and #2 are described in color green and
> blue respectively.
> Cherries taken by Robot #1, `(3 + 2 + 5 + 2) = 12`.
>
> Cherries taken by Robot #2, `(1 + 5 + 5 + 1) = 12`.
> Total of cherries: `12 + 12 = 24`.
>
> Example 2:
>
> [image]
>
> Input: `grid = [[1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[2,0,0,0,0,3,0],[2,0,9,0,0,0,0],[0,3,0,5,4,0,0],[1,0,2,3,0,0,6]]`
>
> Output: 28
>
> Explanation: Path of robot #1 and #2 are described in
> color green and blue respectively.
> Cherries taken by Robot #1, `(1 + 9 + 5 + 2) = 17`.
>
> Cherries taken by Robot #2, `(1 + 3 + 4 + 3) = 11`.
>
> Total of cherries: `17 + 11 = 28`.
>
> #### Constraints:
>
> - `rows == grid.length`
> - `cols == grid[i].length`
> - `2 <= rows, cols <= 70`
> - `0 <= grid[i][j] <= 100`

#### Attempt

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>

struct Solution {
    int map_cherries[70][70][70] = {};

    int cherryPickup(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& grid) {
        std::memset(map_cherries, -1, sizeof(map_cherries));
        const std::size_t row_length = grid.size();
        const std::size_t col_length = grid[0].size();
        return depth_first_search(grid, row_length, col_length, 0, 0, col_length - 1);
    }

private:
    int depth_first_search(
        std::vector<std::vector<int>>& grid,
        const std::size_t row_length,
        const std::size_t col_length,
        int row,
        int left_robot,
        int right_robot
    ) {
        if (row == row_length) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (map_cherries[row][left_robot][right_robot] != -1) {
            return map_cherries[row][left_robot][right_robot];
        }

        int max_cherries = 0;

        for (int left = -1; left < 2; left++) {
            for (int right = -1; right < 2; right++) {
                const int curr_left_robot = left_robot + left;
                const int curr_right_robot = right_robot + right;

                if (curr_left_robot > -1 and curr_left_robot < col_length and curr_right_robot > -1 and curr_right_robot < col_length) {
                    max_cherries = std::max(max_cherries, depth_first_search(
                                                grid,
                                                row_length,
                                                col_length,
                                                row + 1,
                                                curr_left_robot,
                                                curr_right_robot
                                            ));
                }
            }
        }

        int total_cherries = grid[row][left_robot];

        if (left_robot != right_robot) {
            total_cherries += grid[row][right_robot];
        }

        total_cherries += max_cherries;
        return map_cherries[row][left_robot][right_robot] = total_cherries;
    }
};
```

#### Inputs

```
[[3,1,1],[2,5,1],[1,5,5],[2,1,1]]
[[1,0,0,3],[0,0,0,3],[0,0,3,3],[9,0,3,3]]
[[1,10,0,3,86,40],[0,0,0,3,86,40],[0,0,3,3,86,40],[9,0,3,3,86,40], [1,0,40,3,86,40],[0,22,0,3,86,40],[99,0,3,3,86,40],[9,0,3,3,86,40]]
```

#### Outputs

```
24
22
819
```

#### References

- [Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/cherry-pickup-ii/)
- [Discuss](https://leetcode.com/problems/cherry-pickup-ii/discuss/)
- [Solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/cherry-pickup-ii/solution/)

Comment: Drop `= {}`, since you are initialising the array anyway.

Comment: `memset` is not good for initializing if your elements are greater than 1 byte (e.g. `int`).

Comment: You may want to use `std::fill`.  It's another optimized library routine for setting locations to a single value.

Comment: FYI, you may want to consider moving the method contents to a source file.  Remember, every source file that includes the header file will recompile everything in the header file (including the member code).  Placing the code in a source file will restrict the compilation to once.

Comment: @Emma The problem with that array is that the `Solution` object will have a `sizeof()` at least 1.5 megabytes, and that is assuming `sizeof(int) == 4`.  A couple of those, even one, could blow out the stack memory if it's declared locally.  Since you don't know how LeetCode is using `Solution`, then declaring arrays like that should not be an option.

Comment: I would build a tree for each robot with 3 next nodes with possible moves.  Then traverse the tree to find the best possible path for each robot.

Comment: @Emma I plan on it. It seems like a fun exercise.

Comment: @Emma Thanks. FYI for extra credit I will allow N robots with any starting position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be like this:

```
auto map_cherries = std::vector(70, std::vector(70, std::vector(70, -1)));
```

Only works starting from c++17.